# how to call static method on an imported typescript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, methods, ecmascript-6, static

I have 2 packages 
package x
class Log with static properties and methods

import into package y
call the static methods or access static properties

it treats the class name as undefined at runtime

I've tried properties and methods with no parameters

package x, file Log.ts

```
export class Log {
  static test(){console.info('hello from test');}
}
```

package y:

```
import {Log} from 'x';
class y1{
 constructor(){
  Log.test();
 }
}
```

I expect to be able to call the static method.
Instead I get Cannot read property 'test' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is called `Log.ts` - it will be compiled to `Log.js`. Try this:

```
import { Log } from "./Log.js";
class y1 {
    constructor() {
        Log.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Yes that works. It's not how I see other imports working though. I'm pleased it works, but it feels like a workaround. Is this a step to a more elegant solution, or the end result? Thanks Martin

Comment: As I hovered over the original import from, it saw it referenced build/index.
I've now added a line for Log in the corresponding src/index.ts
This makes my import statement work without needing to use the full path.
I'm slightly surprised I need to indicate the export twice. Once in the class definition. Once in the index.ts
I'm also surprised I didn't get a compile error when I didn't have the line in index.ts
Thanks for setting me on the right track Jack.
Martin